# Mudar cor do ícone

Tags: html, ionic, apache-cordova, ionic3

Como faço para mudar a cor de um ícone quando clicado?  Tenho criei ícones personalizados e estão funcionando perfeitamente, mas gostaria de que selecionado, mudasse sua cor. Já tentei de tudo mas não consegui nada ainda. Se alguém puder me ajudar.. por favor.
Meus ícones são assim:
     HTML

```
<div no-padding>
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="Menu" class="SwipedTabs-tabs">

  <ion-segment-button (click)="selectTab(0)">
    <ion-icon name="icon-ico_gastronomia_off"></ion-icon>
  </ion-segment-button>

  <div id='indicator' class="SwipedTabs-indicatorSegment" [ngStyle]=" 
 {'width.%': (100/this.tabs.length)}"></div>
<ion-slides #SwipedTabsSlider (ionSlideDrag)="animateIndicator($event)" 
      (ionSlideWillChange)="updateIndicatorPosition()"
      (ionSlideDidChange)="updateIndicatorPosition()" 
      (pan)="updateIndicatorPosition()" [pager]="false">
      <ion-slide>

      <ion-segment mode="md" [(ngModel)]="Menu">
      <ion-segment-button value="Todosgastronomia" class="round-button" 
      (click)="selecionaprodutoscategoria(1)">
        Todos
      </ion-segment-button>

      <ion-segment-button value="Bareserestaurantes" class="round-button" 
      (click)="selecionaprodutoscategoria(2)">
        Bares & Restaurantes
      </ion-segment-button>
```

scss

```
 .SwipedTabs-indicatorSegment{
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
    -moz-transition:  0.3s all;
    -o-transition:  0.3s all;
    transition:  0.3s all;
    transform-origin: top 0 left 0;
    height: 6px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    background-color: #179c90 !important;

}

// COR GASTRONOMIA/COMPRAS/PASSEIOS  SEGMENTS //
.SwipedTabs-tabs ion-segment-button{
    border:none !important;
    color: carioca!important;
    background-color:white!important;
    background: transparent !important;

    ion-icon:before {
        font-size: 3.7rem !important;    
        color: #393d37;
     }
}

.SwipedTabs-tabs ion-segment-button.SwipedTabs-activeTab{
    color:#179c90     !important;
    width: fit-content !important;

}



.SwipedTabs-tabs
{
    border-bottom: solid 3px #cccabd  !important;
    border:none;
}

.segment-button {

    border-color: #332d2c !important;
    color: #393d37 !important;
    border-width: none !important;
    flex: auto !important;
    background: transparent;

    &.activated, &.segment-activated {   

    //border-bottom: 2px solid red !important;
                     //Corresponde a cor das subcategorias ativas
    color:#179c90  !important;  

    background-color: rgba(53, 52, 52, 0.089) !important;

                       //Corresponde a cor do ícone ativo
    ion-icon:Before {
    font-size: 4rem ;    
    background: transparent;
    color: #179c90;

    }   

    }
}

    ion-segment-button {
    border-style: none;
    color: #179c90;
    height: 6px;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    text-transform: none !important;  
    max-width: 100% !important;
```

Comment: Esses ícones estão dentro de em algum outro componente, por exemplo de algum botão?

Comment: @GabrielCarvalho quero quando clicado.  Tenho 4 icones em segment buttons, quero que quando clicar em algum, ele mude da cor cinza para azul por exemplo, apenas o selecionado.

Comment: @Renata  <ion-segment-button (click)="selectTab(0)">
        <ion-icon name="icon-ico_gastronomia_off"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>

Comment: Algo que parece estar faltando é incluir `value = "Todosgastronomia"` no `ion-segment-button` correspondente do primeiro bloco (o que tem os ícones).

Comment: @Renata mais uma vez, Muito obrigado. Me salvou novamente. Estou há tanto tempo nesse problema e era uma coisa simples até.  :s   Obrigado! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode alterar a cor pelo arquivo theme/variables.scss, mas só encontrei a solução para IOS. Exemplo, alterando a cor para vermelho:

```
$segment-button-ios-text-color: red;
```

Outra opção pode ser alterar diretamente pelo .scss da página. Exemplo:

```
.segment .segment-button {
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
    border-color: grey;
}

.segment .segment-button.segment-activated {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: usando sua resposta, mudou apenas os botoes de baixo como na imagem. 

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4doA.png

Mas reparei agora, que uso ion segment button para o icone e para os botoes abaixo,  logo está tudo uma zona, acho q por isso nao devo estar conseguindo alterar as cores =s

Comment: editei minha pergunta, se puder ver se tem algo de errado no codigo, apesar de eu achar que sim. Ainda estou aprendendo então posso estar fazendo errado algumas coisas

Comment: @Felipe XST, você pode incluir seu código do arquivo html também?

Comment: Pronto.  Não está completo, tem oturos ícones mas essa é a base